# Calculate Average from Data Table colmns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Trying to manipulate the data in the following datatable to allow me to calculate averages.

I want to add all the data in PktsRecieved(XAxis) and PktsRecieved(YAxis) and calculate an average

Should I use a Linq query or what is the best way of doing this

Thanks

```
List<string[]> rows = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\\Final Year\\Uni\\NoCAnalysisTool2\\rx.csv")
   .Select(x => x.Split(','))
   .ToList();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Source|Destination");
dt.Columns.Add("PktsRecieved(XAxis)");
dt.Columns.Add(" ");
dt.Columns.Add("Source|Destination ");
dt.Columns.Add("PktsRecieved(YAxis)");
dt.Columns.Add("");
dt.Columns.Add("");
dt.Columns.Add("");


rows.ForEach(x => { dt.Rows.Add(x); });
dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I'm reading it right, your biggest problem might be that the data is in strings.  Off the top of my head, I'd suggest something like this:

```
double averageXAxis = rows.Average( (r) => double.Parse(r[1]) );
```

(forgive me if the syntax isn't completely correct - I'm typing it freehand without VS at the moment.)

But like I said, you might have a problem in that your data is technically in a string format coming from a .CSV - which means there could technically be anything in it - numbers, letters, weird non-ascii chars, etc.  You might have to add additional LINQ statements to narrow it down to only the rows that have a parse-able value in the column.  You probably don't want to code it in a way that a single blank/rogue value causes the whole code to Exception.

Edit: If you need to operate on the DataTable and don't have access to that rows object?  You can use the AsEnumerable() function to get a row enumeration on the DataTable and do the same sort of LINQ trick with .Average(...)